# Implement iMessage programmatically

Tags: ios, imessage

I am thinking to include iMessage feature in my iOS app. Can we customize it through programming in iOS? I want user can block/disable particular user in group chat. is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No this is not possible, Apple does not provide any API for interacting with iMessage. You could have easily found this out with some simple web searches or having a look at the Apple iOS API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do in iOS 10 with new framework of iMessageApp.

Comment: Well yes and no, you still can't block user. But a user will be able to interactie with your app from iMessage.