# How to get sms /iMessage count of incoming and outgoing with private api without jailbreaking the phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-privateapi

I'm interested in just getting the count of incoming and outgoing messages to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no private API through you can get count of SMS / iMessage.

[Implement iMessage programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293578/implement-imessage-programatically)

With iOS 10 you could use it as extension but cant get its statistics.

https://developer.apple.com/imessage/

**Addition**

Nope, http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/ChatKit.framework using chatKit you can send and read iMessage / SMS , but cant access other details like count, all message date, senders etc .

When user read iMessage message , `CKConversationMessageReadNotification` notification getting posted. and you could observe notification and access its details.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myTarget selector:@selector(readAwesomeMessage:) name:@"CKConversationMessageReadNotification" object:nil];

-(void)readAwesomeMessage:(NSNotification *)notif {

CKIMMessage *msg = notif.userInfo[@"CKMessageKey"]; 
//CKIMMessage *msg = [[notif userInfo] objectForKey:@"CKMessageKey"]; -->long way that does the same as the line above

//...
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression, that you can get access to some data, via ChatKit framework. I just don't know which methods have are responsible for that.